vscode remote ssh - settings for all users on server
I look after some development servers and a lot of developers/engineers use vscode. We have had an issue where our /home is really small and one of the vscode extensions filled it up and then caused a lot of issues.
The C/C++ extension has settings to control where and how much it caches. C_Cpp.intelliSenseCachePath and C_Cpp.intelliSenseCacheSize.
Is there any way to get VScode to load default extension settings from the server or do I need to tell each user to change their settings?

Default settings do exist for intelliSense, which unfortunately are built-in.
The default path value is ${workspaceFolder}/.vscode and the default
cache size is 5 GB.
There have been several feature requests about these defaults.
Request
Disable IntelliSense caching by default? #3616
was refused by developer sean-mcmanus:

5 GB is also the default used by VS and we haven't gotten enough user feedback to lower that default to 1 GB.

Feature request
 Change the default intelliSenseCachePath/databaseFilename to "~/.cpptools" instead of ${workspaceFolder}/.vscode and ${workspaceStorage} #3664
got some discussion, but no action.
The announcement of
Visual Studio Code C/C++ extension: March 2019 Update
only said this:

IntelliSense Cache Settings
By default, the cached PCH files are currently stored in your
workspace folder’s “.vscode” folder under the subdirectory ‘ipch’.
You change this location via the “C_Cpp.intelliSenseCachePath”
setting. You can also control how much disk space can be used for the
cache with the “C_Cpp.intelliSenseCacheSize” setting. The cached PCH
files can be large, depending on the size and number of #include
header files. The default cache size (for all files under the
C_Cpp.intelliSenseCachePath) is 5120 MB. IntelliSense caching can be
disabled by setting the cache size to 0.

As you see, no changes were made to the configuration to allow for
global settings.
My conclusion: The current situation is that each user needs to manually
change this setting, and for each project.
